# cake bake all except Test

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-bake

I wonder how could I use the `cake bake all` command without filling the Test folder.

Because I'm getting an error, when I use this command :

```
Fatal Error Error: Call to undefined method App::getAssociated() in [C:\wamp\www
\myAppFolder\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\TestTask.php, line 394]
```

Everything works except Test baking, so `cake bake all` bakes Controller & Model but it fails when baking Test before baking Views...

In my job, we don't have time to care about Tests so if someone knows a way to block the test baking... would be a lot helpful !

**EDIT :**

If someone knows a way to fix the Fatal Error instead... Hint : I have this issue since I installed PHPUnit.

Answer (score 1):

"All" means "all". Did you look at [the documentation?](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html)

To bake the views run

```
cake bake view
```

You can script any or all of these:

```
cake bake db_config
cake bake model
cake bake view
cake bake controller
cake bake project
cake bake fixture
cake bake test
cake bake plugin plugin_name
```

Or use the interactive shell.

Comment: I know how to bake only View... that wasn't the question here. Currently I need to use at least 2 commands per entity to get what I should get with cake bake all...

Comment: So the put the items you want to bake in a script and call that; I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: you mean a bash or something wich execute cake bake controller, cake bake model and cake bake view... each after each ?

Comment: hum... not really what I expected but it could be an alternative =/ thanks

Comment: Or just clean up your tests so it builds.

Comment: yep could be THE fix... but i've no idea how